# The resizing window issue with Android Studio recent update (1.2)

Tags: android-studio

Recently updated my Android Studio from 1.1 to 1.2 and I am facing this strange issue. 
Trying to resize my window and it doesn't seem to work. Only you can shorten the width, not height. 
So unless I can shorten the height, I cannot click the Finish button. ^_^

[image]

Comment: I ran into this problem as well, I don't understand why vertical resizing is not allowed, there is plenty of empty space... very frustrating!

Comment: Posted My Solution: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=168828#c47

Answer (score 4):

You should change the Theme as follow:

File-->Settings-->Appearance & Behavior-->Appearance--> Here you should change the Theme from "IntliJ" to "Windows", and then click OK.

Comment: Not working for me. I am using `Android Studio 2.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one thing seems to work for it.

You can Right Click on Taskbar > properties > Auto-hide Taskbar

Then you'd be able to click the **Finish** button.

Comment: Just downloaded the new patch update of Android Studio. The above mentioned problem still exists. And sometimes, its gets really annoying to auto-hide taskbar before adding any new Activity. Anyway, I hope Android Studio developes might do something about it.

Comment: While this works for some Windows users, it takes a lot more configuration for me to hide the top Activities bar on Ubuntu14.04 with the Gnome desktop, so much so that I don't want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Update to Android Studio 1.4 or latter.
Then you'd be able to click the Finish button.
[Android studio 1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP0LB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use TAB button, in case you do not want to Auto-Hide Taskbar.
Same happens with Emulator too. I also tried reseting the X and Y coordinates to 0, but it still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been using the enter key to finish and the X at the top right of the window to cancel. Switching to Windows theme also fixes this, but as someone who uses Darcula for ease on the eyes, I would find it time consuming to switch back and forth on a regular basis.